# How to transport varialbes between different threads in Python?

Tags: python

I want to transport varialbes between  different threads in Python.
example:

```
import para
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import opencv-python as cv2
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage
from numba import cuda
import os  
import systematrix
import an_matrix
import time
import torch

@cuda.jit
def test(pp):
    
    if cuda.blockIdx.x==0:
        print("dx=",cuda.threadIdx.x)
        if cuda.threadIdx.x<pp:
            #print("ppppp")
            print("dd=",pp)
            pp=cuda.threadIdx.x
            print("dd_af",pp)


if __name__ == '__main__':


    pp=999
    test[1,16](pp)
    print("pp=",pp)
```

By these codes, I want get the minimum number. But it's failed! How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

the pp variable is local to the function, meaning it cannot be accessed from outside of the function. to make it accessible, we first need to make it a global variable, and then make it a mutable object.

```py
import para
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import opencv-python as cv2
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage
from numba import cuda
import os  
import systematrix
import an_matrix
import time
import torch

pp = [999]

@cuda.jit
def test(pp):
    
    if cuda.blockIdx.x==0:
        print("dx=",cuda.threadIdx.x)
        if cuda.threadIdx.x<pp[0]:
            #print("ppppp")
            print("dd=",pp[0])
            pp[0]=cuda.threadIdx.x
            print("dd_af",pp[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test[1,16](pp)
    print("pp=",pp[0])
```

here, i am making pp a one element array as an array is mutable: the memory doesnt change, so no matter where you are calling it from, the variable should always point to the same spot, so you can modify it.

Comment: I have change the codes. But it can't work!

Comment: oh i forgot the parameter is no longer needed

Comment: @heresypedanter i edited my answer. it should now work

Comment: I have cancel the parameter.But it still can't work! just displaying"Use of unsupported opcode (STOR_GLOBAL) found"

Comment: can u post the error?

Comment: "aise UnsupportedError(msg, loc=self.get_debug_loc(inst.lineno))
numba.core.errors.UnsupportedError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
Use of unsupported opcode (STORE_GLOBAL) found

File "main.py", line 32:
def test():
    <source elided>
                        print("dd=",pp)
                        pp=cuda.threadIdx.x

Comment: this seems like a software issue. looks like it cannot understand how the global keyboard is used. ill edit my answer to provide a different technique

Comment: For your lates suggestion , I have changed. It can't work. displaying "

 

There are 16 candidate implementations:
    - Of which 16 did not match due to:
    Overload of function 'getitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
      With argument(s): '(int64, int64)':
     No match.

During: typing of intrinsic-call at D:\SART_CT_gpu\main.py (29)
During: typing of static-get-item at D:\SART_CT_gpu\main.py (29)

File "main.py", line 29:
def test(pp):
    <source elided>
                print("dx=",cuda.threadIdx.x)
                if cuda.threadIdx.x<pp[0]:

Comment: @heresypedanter that seems like an issue with your software. i cant help with that